# How to solve the following set of integrals by using Hypergeometric functions?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

Any recommendations to help me to solve this integral
$$
\int_{-\sqrt{x}+y}^{1-y} 
   \left(1-(t+y)^2\right)^{r}
   \left(1-x(t-y)^2 \right)^{r} dt
$$
where $\{r,x,y\} \in \mathbb{R}  , \, |y|<1+x, \, \, r\ge0$,
I used the taylor series to expand the $ \left(1-(t-y)^2\right)^{r}$ around $y=0$ and $\left(1-x(t-y)^2 \right)^{r}$  around $\sqrt{x}y=0$ and then i multiplied the expansions together.

After that i divided the resultant seris to 4 series, 1st and 2nd represents even-even and odd-odd terms and 3rd and 4th represents odd-even and even-odd terms.
Now I am trying to solve these integrals:

1st
$$
\int_{-x+y}^{1-y} (2t)^{2 (p+q)}
   \left(1-t^2\right)^{-m-p+r}
   \left(1-x t^2 \right)^{-n-q+r} dt
$$
2nd
$$
\int_{-x+y}^{1-y} (2t)^{2 (p+q+1)}
   \left(1-t^2\right)^{-1-m-p+r}
   \left(1-x t^2 \right)^{-1-n-q+r} dt
$$
3rd
$$
\int_{-x+y}^{1-y} (2t)^{2 (p+q)+1}
   \left(1-t^2\right)^{-1-m-p+r}
   \left(1-x t^2 \right)^{-n-q+r} dt
$$
4th
$$
\int_{-x+y}^{1-y} (2t)^{2 (p+q)+1}
   \left(1-t^2\right)^{-m-p+r}
   \left(1-x t^2 \right)^{-1-n-q+r} dt
$$
where $ \{m,n,p,q\} \in \mathbb{N}$.
I think the solution will be in terms of hypergeometric functions or incomplete beta function, but i can't find the solution myself. I would be grateful if anyone can help.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5Bt%5Ea*%281+-+t%5E2%29%5Eb*%281+-+t%5E2*x%29%5Ec%2Ct%5D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the antiderivatives are
$$I(a,b,c)=\int t^a\, \left(1-t^2\right)^b \,\left(1-t^2 x\right)^c\,dt$$
$$I(a,b,c)=\frac{t^{a+1} }{a+1}\,F_1\left(\frac{a+1}{2};-b,-c;\frac{a+3}{2};t^2,t^2 x\right)$$ where appears  the [Appell hypergeometric function of two variables](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html).